# How do I find what npm package has a particular dependency?

Tags: npm, package.json

My webpack project has a new error:

> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

Which I haven't solved yet, but the underlying problem is: I don't have **caniuse-lite** in my package.json - so where is it?

*btw: running that command makes no difference.*

It's obviously a dependency or a dependency of a dependency, ad infinitum...

[npmjs caniuse-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caniuse-lite) lists 80 dependent packages.

Is there a way to search the dependency graph of packages to easily find what package in my package.json file is the parent that somewhere along the line depends on caniuse-lite?

Comment: In case anyone else gets this error: updating @babel/preset-env to the latest version 7.3.4 resolved the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily check that by following way.

Checkout more here : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

`npm ls contextify`

```
app-name@0.0.1 /home/zorbash/some-project
└─┬ d3@3.3.6
  └─┬ jsdom@0.5.7
    └── contextify@0.1.15
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks.  The parent package was:  @babel/preset-env@7.1.0